# Why do programs run after I close them?

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur

I am more familiar with Windows and Linux where when I close the application window, the application is closed.

On Mac Big Sur, commonly, when I close an application, a small dot exists under the icon in the dock, indicating the program is still running. Why is this?

For example, while on Linux or Windows, when I close my sole Visual Studio Code window, the application completely closes. The process is completely gone. When I close vscode on mac, a small dot still exists in the doc, and when I open activity monitor, I can see the 'Code' process is still running.

Comment: Why would closing a document close the program? It’s been like this since 1984 on Mac and before then on unix for most window managers of that era.

Comment: Not closing a document.... closing the main application window closes an application on literally every version of Windows and Linux I have ever used. Not sure what wack OS you are using....

Comment: some of us cut our teeth on wack OS from well before Windows or Linux were born. I won’t tell you to get off the lawn, but consider what kind of workman blames their tools... (heck, [Microsoft cut its GUI teeth programming for Macintosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_version_history#Windows_1.0))

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/why-mac-applications-never-get-closed might provide some more insights on this, including historical aspects beyond Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows or Linux an app's window usually **is** the app. However, macOS is different, as traditionally the app windows can be closed with the app still running (with few exceptions). The *menu bar* at the top of the screen shows you which app is currently active (there can be only one active app), and even if you close all windows of an app it will still be running and you will be able to control it with the *menu bar*.

The red circle closes the window and not the app, same is true for the <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut (or <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for closing all the windows of the active app).

To quit the app you can do one of the following:

- pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the active app
- clicking on the app name in the top left corner of your screen (on your *menu bar*) and selecting **Quit** in the menu to quit the active app
- right clicking (or <kbd>^ ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>) on the app bar in the *dock* and selecting **Quit**
- selecting the app in the `Activity Monitor` (`Applications`>`Utilities`>`Activity Monitor`) and using the **Force quit** button in its top left corner (useful for unresponsive apps)
- pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> to open the `Force Quit Applications` window (useful for unresponsive apps)

You can read more about Mac window management [here](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/guide/mac-help/mchlp2469/mac) and about quitting apps [here](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/guide/mac-help/mchl834d18c2/11.0/mac/11.0).

Answer (score 1):

It is the mechanism differences between the operating systems. The red dot you press to "close" app doesn't actually terminates the program rather closes the window which the app is running. Closing window shortcut for MacOS is CMD+W which does the same thing as clicking the red dot.

In order to terminate a program, you need to use the shortcut of CMD+Q, otherwise the program will be idle in the background.

Shortly: ALT+F4 is equal to CMD+Q in MacOS

PS: Some applications does not support CMD+W shortcut and red dot acts as CMD+Q. Native Instruments Traktor and Microsoft Teams are the ones I have seen not supporting this.